How to use lookup_tables in Rasa NLU?
I tried to find information in documentation:
https://learning.rasa.com/conversational-ai-with-rasa/entities/
and in here
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu-training-data/#lookup-tables
but I can not seam to find end to end implementation
I created txt with colors in my project, in my config I wrote:
  lookup_tables:
    colors:
      elements: "colors.txt"

in my nlu.yml:
- intent: what_colors
  examples: |
      - Do you like [red](colors)
      - I like [blue](colors)?
      - I love [green](colors)


in my stories.yml:
- story: what colors do you like
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: what_colors
  - action: action_colors

I also have actions.py:
class ActionColors(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_colors"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        color = next(tracker.get_latest_entity_values("color"), None)

        colors_names = np.loadtxt('colors.txt')

        if color  in colors_names:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="You choose: " + color + ".")
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"There is no color like: {color} in colors file.")

        return []

in my domain I have:
entities:
 - colors

and when I train, run rasa actions and rasa shell, I ask "Do you like red?" I only gets fallback response, what did I do wrong? where in documentation can I find full path to implement "lookup tables"?
I know that config.yml requires "RegexEntityExtractor" & "RegexFeaturizer" but when I am implementing this I got:
"UserWarning: Failed to load RegexEntityExtractor from model storage. This can happen if the model could not be trained because regexes could not be extracted from the given training data - and hence could not be persisted."

I found that my main problem whas wrong config.yml
this is my config.yml when my lookup tables are working:
pipeline:
    - name: WhitespaceTokenizer
    - name: RegexFeaturizer
    - name: RegexEntityExtractor
    - name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
    - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
    - name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
      analyzer: char_wb
      min_ngram: 1
      max_ngram: 4
    - name: DIETClassifier
      epochs: 100
      constrain_similarities: True
    - name: EntitySynonymMapper
    - name: FallbackClassifier
      threshold: 0.7
      ambiguity_threshold: 0.1

policies:

I still have problemst with txt but when I have them in my nlu.yml they are working:
- intent: zamówienie
  examples: |
      - What color do you know [green](color)
      - What color do you like [green](color)
      - Do you know [green](color), it is my favorite color!

- lookup: Restaurant
  examples: |
    - green
    - red
    - purple
    - yellow
    - black
    - white
    - grey
    - orange
    - pink

